# Getting mcrypt_encrypt(): Key of size 51 not supported by this algorithm. Only keys of sizes 16, 24 or 32 supported

Tags: php, laravel, mcrypt

I have a laravel 5.0 app running in my office. It was developed by someone else. Suddenly sometimes it started to give me the following Error.

```
mcrypt_encrypt(): Key of size 51 not supported by this algorithm. Only keys of sizes 16, 24 or 32 supported
```

In my .env file i have the following APP KEY:

```
APP_KEY=VCkUaWOvNSZc4ZB2A03qUscJ37vkCCvJ
```

As far as i know this error occurs when your app key is not 16,24 or 32 charecter length. My app key is 32 charecter length. So it should not show this error.

To solve this I tried resetting the app key by running:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

As the problem was not fixed i changed the key in app.php with the following line:

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'y6a1orkvfhQ7Sr3e1SZnPdFUpmP6Abfi'),
```

Even that did not solve the problem. Why i am still getting the error even if my key is 32 character

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?  Is there any pattern to when you get the error?

Comment: I am using php version 5.6. i did not find any pattern.I am wondering where it is getting 51 character key when i have set it to 32 character. should i reset key and clear config cache ?